# Get handles for all children + windows of a process from PID in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, windows, winapi

How do I list all the handles of all the children and windows of a process using only its PID?

For example, I need the handles of hidden windows, minimized windows, buttons, text boxes, group boxes, tab controls etc (basically everything). All I have is the PID of the process to begin with.

Thanks!

Comment: Creatively combine the following ingredients: [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx), [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx), and [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494.aspx).

Comment: Or avoid P/Invoking then use a modern technique as [Microsoft UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this with some Googling skills :)

1. used EnumWindows to enumerate all top level windows
2. Passed window handles to GetWindowThreadProcessId to obtain owner Process ID
3. Compared PID with process under examination
4. Used EnumChildWindows if PID matched
5. Added SendMessage to obtain any Text and GetClassName to display Class

Thanks everyone!